# right click on label and popup menu, how can i get the button from the menu item select listener?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3, contextmenu, listener

I created tens of **Label** over a **Group**, I added a right click menu for every Label, and then attached an event **listener** to the menu, then How I can get the exact Label which I right-clicked on via the menu item select listener (**ContextMenuEvent.MENU_ITEM_SELECT**)? Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to create a custom component, which contains Label and Menu skin parts. This way you can also skin the component any way you want, and have access to the label as well as the menu in a very easy way.

To solve your problem, let's assume the skin parts are named 'label' and 'menu'. When a ContextMenuEvent is dispatched, you can access the clicked menu, by accessing the event.target property, in the menu click handler. Now, its parent will be available via its **parent** property, and this is how you can access the label component, or skin part. So, it will be something like this:

**event.target.parent.label**

Where:

**event.target** - the menu component

**event.target.parent** - your component which wraps around a label and a menu

**event.target.parent.label** - the component you want to access

To summarize, create a custom component, which wraps around a label and a menu, that become its skin parts. This way, by identifying any of the two parts (e.g. in an event handler), you can easily determine the other corresponding component, via the **parent** property.

You might need to cast the **event.target** value to the menu class, and the **event.target.parent** property, to your custom component class, then the label will be available.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Label as component than you can access it by:

```
event.contextMenuOwner.text
```

or

If you are using button than you can access it by:

```
event.contextMenuOwner.label
```

Hope this may help.

Answer (score 0):

When ever I click on any menu item it's mouseTarget property will contain the iformation abut it's parent.

```
// Handler when customized menu items are selected.       
private function menuItemHandler(event:ContextMenuEvent):void {
        var obj:InteractiveObject = event.mouseTarget;
        if(obj is Label)
             Alert.show(Label(obj).id);
}
```

Check if this helps you.

Small App.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600"
               creationComplete="init()">

    <s:layout>
        <s:BasicLayout/>
    </s:layout>
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.controls.Alert;

            [Bindable]
            private var cm:ContextMenu;
            private var cmi:ContextMenuItem;

            private var item1:ContextMenuItem;
            private var item2:ContextMenuItem;
            private var item3:ContextMenuItem;
            private var item4:ContextMenuItem;
            private var item5:ContextMenuItem;

            private function init():void
            {
                cmi = new ContextMenuItem("Some Context Item");
                cmi.enabled = false;

                item1 = new ContextMenuItem("Customized item", true);
                item2 = new ContextMenuItem("Enable/Disable customized menu entry", true);
                item3 = new ContextMenuItem("Visible/Invisible customized menu entry");
                item4 = new ContextMenuItem("Copy\u00A0");
                item5 = new ContextMenuItem("More Flex tutorials", true);

                // Manage clicks on your customized items
                item1.addEventListener(ContextMenuEvent.MENU_ITEM_SELECT, menuItemHandler);
                item2.addEventListener(ContextMenuEvent.MENU_ITEM_SELECT, menuItemHandler);
                item3.addEventListener(ContextMenuEvent.MENU_ITEM_SELECT, menuItemHandler);
                item4.addEventListener(ContextMenuEvent.MENU_ITEM_SELECT, menuItemHandler);
                item5.addEventListener(ContextMenuEvent.MENU_ITEM_SELECT, menuItemHandler);

                cm = new ContextMenu();
                cm.hideBuiltInItems();
                cm.customItems = [cmi, item1, item2, item3, item4, item5];
                cm.addEventListener(ContextMenuEvent.MENU_SELECT, onMnuSelect);
            }

            private function onMnuSelect(event:ContextMenuEvent):void
            {
                /* var obj:InteractiveObject = event.mouseTarget;
                if(obj is Label)
                    Alert.show(Label(obj).id); */
            }

            // Handler when customized menu items are selected.       
            private function menuItemHandler(event:ContextMenuEvent):void {
                var obj:InteractiveObject = event.mouseTarget;
                if(obj is Label)
                    Alert.show(Label(obj).id);
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:VGroup>
        <s:Label id="label1" text="label1" contextMenu="{cm}"/>
        <s:Label id="label2" text="label2" contextMenu="{cm}"/>
        <s:Label id="label3" text="label3" contextMenu="{cm}"/>
        <s:Label id="label4" text="label4" contextMenu="{cm}"/>
    </s:VGroup>


</s:Application>
```